# Want to output two values from each line of a huge JSONL file in R Studio

Tags: r

I'm walking through a huge JSONL file (100G, 100M rows) line by line extracting two key values from the data. Ideally, I want this written to a file with two columns.  I'm a real beginner here.

Here is an example of the JSON on each row of the file referenced on my C drive:
https://api.unpaywall.org/v2/10.6118/jmm.2017.23.2.135?email=YOUR_EMAIL

```
or:
{
    "best_oa_location": {
        "evidence": "open (via page says license)",
        "host_type": "publisher",
        "is_best": true,
        "license": "cc-by-nc",
        "pmh_id": null,
        "updated": "2018-02-14T11:18:21.978814",
        "url": "FAKEURL",
        "url_for_landing_page": "URL2",
        "url_for_pdf": "URL4",
        "version": "publishedVersion"
    },
    "data_standard": 2,
    "doi": "10.6118/jmm.2017.23.2.135",
    "doi_url": "URL5",
    "genre": "journal-article",
    "is_oa": true,
    "journal_is_in_doaj": false,
    "journal_is_oa": false,
    "journal_issns": "2288-6478,2288-6761",
    "journal_name": "Journal of Menopausal Medicine",
    "oa_locations": [
        {
            "evidence": "open (via page says license)",
            "host_type": "publisher",
            "is_best": true,
            "license": "cc-by-nc",
            "pmh_id": null,
            "updated": "2018-02-14T11:18:21.978814",
            "url": "URL6",
            "url_for_landing_page": "hURL7": "hURL8",
            "version": "publishedVersion"
        },
        {
            "evidence": "oa repository (via OAI-PMH doi match)",
            "host_type": "repository",
            "is_best": false,
            "license": "cc-by-nc",
            "pmh_id": "oai:pubmedcentral.nih.gov:5606912",
            "updated": "2017-10-21T18:12:39.724143",
            "url": "URL9",
            "url_for_landing_page": "URL11",
            "url_for_pdf": "URL12",
            "version": "publishedVersion"
        },
        {
            "evidence": "oa repository (via pmcid lookup)",
            "host_type": "repository",
            "is_best": false,
            "license": null,
            "pmh_id": null,
            "updated": "2018-10-11T01:49:34.280389",
            "url": "URL13",
            "url_for_landing_page": "URL14",
            "url_for_pdf": null,
            "version": "publishedVersion"
        }
    ],
    "published_date": "2017-01-01",
    "publisher": "The Korean Society of Menopause (KAMJE)",
    "title": "A Case of Granular Cell Tumor of the Clitoris in a Postmenopausal Woman",
    "updated": "2018-06-20T20:31:37.509896",
    "year": 2017,
    "z_authors": [
        {
            "affiliation": [
                {
                    "name": "Department of Obstetrics and Gynecology, Soonchunhyang University Cheonan Hospital, University of Soonchunhyang College of Medicine, Cheonan, Korea."
                }
            ],
            "family": "Min",
            "given": "Ji-Won"
        },
        {
            "affiliation": [
                {
                    "name": "Department of Obstetrics and Gynecology, Soonchunhyang University Cheonan Hospital, University of Soonchunhyang College of Medicine, Cheonan, Korea."
                }
            ],
            "family": "Kim",
            "given": "Yun-Sook"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the code i'm using/wrote:

```
library (magrittr)

library (jqr)

con = file("C:/users/ME/desktop/miniunpaywall.jsonl", "r");

while ( length(line <- readLines(con, n = -1)) > 0) {

write.table( line %>% jq ('.doi,.best_oa_location.license'), file='test.txt', quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE);}
```

What results from this is a line of text for each row of JSON that looks like this:

```
"10.1016/j.ijcard.2018.10.014,CC-BY"
```

This is effectively:

```
"[DOI],[LICENSE]"
```

I want ideally to have the output be:

```
[DOI] tab [LICENSE]
```

I believe my problem is that I'm writing the values as a string into a single column when i say:

```
write.table( line %>% jq ('.doi,.best_oa_location.license')
```

I havent figured out a way to remove the quotes i'm getting around each line in my file or how i could separate the two values with a tab.  I feel I'm pretty close.  Help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you able to provide a small example of what you're trying to achieve, with a JSON data set you can include in your question (even if it's only 3 or 4 lines), which demonstrates your issue, and so others can simply copy & paste your data and code to see what you're doing?

Comment: I cant paste the JSON example as it has links and I dont have the reputation :(  I'll see if i can attach it as a file